# chrome frame - not working in local machine

Tags: google-chrome, frame

I have installed chrome frame in IE 8. Then in the HTML page I added the below meta tag

This works fine when I upload the HTML page online and tested. But when I test the same locally it is not working.

Please advise how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you solved this? How?

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is create a new registry entry that will allow you to prefix any URL with "gcf:".

You can find the instructions here: http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started#TOC-Testing-Your-Sites

Once you have created the registry entry, you can now force IE to use Chrome Frame by prefixing the URL like so:

```
gcf:http://www.google.com
```

or

```
gcf:C:\tests\chromeFrameTest.html
```